# how to use regex [or] in split javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have string in user is dynamic (user or users) and i want get string: abc

i have block code:

```
var str = '<span><a href="domain.com/user/abc/"></span>';

var s = str.split('<a href="domain.com/(?:user|users)/')
s=s[1].split('">')[0];
```

any solution can define regex in split.

Thankyou your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more solution. First split the string with separator `/`.

Suppose that should be either *user* or *users* in the result array.

Property indexOf of absent element equals -1. And 'abc' (or smth else) will always be the next to user|users.

So, index of 'abc' will be `indexOf(present element) + indexOf(absent element) + 2`. Thus it's simplest way to find 'abc'

```
var str = '<span><a href="domain.com/user/abc/"></span>';
var s = str.split('/');
s = s[s.indexOf('user') + s.indexOf('users')+2]
```

Comment: thankyou. This is the most suitable solution when string `user` is dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var mySubString = str.split('user').pop().split('/')[1];
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLpyJM?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only user is variable, you can split for all '/' characters.

```
var str = '<span><a href="domain.com/user/abc/"></span>';
var s = str.split('/');
console.log(s[2]);
```